# Hide Floating Action Button after clicking it

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

I'd like to know how to make the Floating Action Bar disappear upon clicking it. The action it performs is within the same fragment so I can't simply load another activity or fragment, which lacks the FAB. I tried to use

```
fab.setVisibility(view.GONE);
```

in its onClickListener:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        writeProfile();
        fab.setVisibility(view.GONE);
    }
});
```

But of course you can't access a variable from within an inner class.

EDIT: The Accepted answer works to hide the FAB but how then can I un-hide the FAB from another method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to the app:layout_anchor attribute. You must get rid of the anchor before changing visibility:

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams p = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
p.setAnchorId(View.NO_ID);
fab.setLayoutParams(p);
fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: This works if I declare the FAB final. Now how do I get the FAB to re-appear in another method call outside of the FAB class?